# listagg data to useable format?

Tags: database, oracle, concatenation, listagg

This is my first time working with the LISTAGG function and I'm confused. I can select the data easily enough, but the characters of the `USERS` column all have spaces in between them, and when trying to copypaste it, no data from that column is copied. I've tried with two different IDEs. Am I doing something wrong?

Example:

```
select course_id, listagg(firstname, ', ') within group (order by course_id) as users
    from (
      select distinct u.firstname, u.lastname, u.student_id, cm.course_id
      from course_users cu
      join users u on u.pk1 = cu.users_pk1
      join course_main cm on cm.pk1 = cu.crsmain_pk1
      and cm.course_id like '2015SP%'
      )
group by course_id;
```

Yields:

[image: LISTAGG result]

Comment: Can you tell us what "formatted strangely" means? What is the expected output that you are not getting?

Comment: @ruudvan Edited for clarity. The characters of the `USERS` column all have spaces in between them, and when trying to copypaste it, no data from that column is copied.

Comment: The subquery return users firstname without spaces?

Comment: Not being able to copy is probably due to something in the IDE. Which IDE are you using? (like Toad or plsql developer)?
Also, there doesn't seem to be anything in the query that adds spaces. Run the subquery independently to make sure that the table doesn't have those spaces in the data.

Comment: @ruudvan I've tried both dbForge Studio Express and Oracle SQL Developer. Both have the same behavior.

Comment: @Aramillo yes, the subquery displays normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `firstname` column seems to be defined as `nvarchar2`:

```
with t as (
  select '2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A'as course_id,
    cast('Alissa' as nvarchar2(10)) as firstname
  from dual
  union all select '2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A'as course_id,
    cast('Dorothea' as nvarchar2(10)) as firstname
  from dual
)
select course_id, listagg(firstname, ', ')
  within group (order by course_id) as users
from t
group by course_id;

COURSE_ID            USERS                         
-------------------- ------------------------------
2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A
```

... and I can't copy/paste the users values from SQL Developer either, but it displays with spaces, as you can see from SQL*Plus:

```
COURSE_ID            USERS
-------------------- ------------------------------
2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A  A l i s s a,  D o r o t h e a
```

As the documentation says, the `listagg()` function always returns `varchar2` (or `raw`), so passing in an `nvarchar2` value causes an implicit conversion which is throwing out your results.

If you're stuck with your column being of that data type, you could cast it to `varchar2` inside the `listagg` call:

```
column users format a30
with t as (
  select '2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A'as course_id,
    cast('Alissa' as nvarchar2(10)) as firstname
  from dual
  union all select '2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A'as course_id,
    cast('Dorothea' as nvarchar2(10)) as firstname
  from dual
)
select course_id, listagg(cast(firstname as varchar2(10)), ', ')
  within group (order by course_id) as users
from t
group by course_id;

COURSE_ID            USERS                         
-------------------- ------------------------------
2015SP.BOS.PPB.556.A Alissa, Dorothea
```

But you probably don't really want it to be `nvarchar2` at all.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem, it turned out that the problem was with encoding. I got this solved like this (change to another encoding if needed):

```
...listagg(convert(firstname, 'UTF8', 'AL16UTF16'), ', ')...
```

Comment: [Oracle discourages the use of `convert`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions034.htm) though, as noted in the documentation; even if this is to correct data that has been stored in a wrong character set.. If you have a discrepancy between `varchar2` and `nvarchar2` storage then casting seems more appropriate. If you have a wider character set problem then this might not be safe. Depends, as so many things do...

Comment: @AlexPoole why so? The article seems to indicate that this IS the time when it should be used.

Comment: @Cliff - just pointing out the warning. If the two character sets are your DB and national character set then it'll work, but I'd be looking at why you have the wrong character set in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently it's a known (unresolved?) bug in 11. TO_CHAR() worked for me...

```
SELECT wiporderno, LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(medium), ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY wiporderno) AS jobclassification
```

...where medium was the problematic column/data type.

Comment: IMO it worth adding the bug# and a short description: `Bug 19461687  LISTAGG return value contains ASCII 0x00 bytes for NVARCHAR with no delimiter specified (MOS Doc ID: 19461687.8)`