# Using listagg with Polish characters

Tags: sql, oracle, polish, listagg

I am having a little problem with 'listagg' function. I want to use it to concatenate rows into one string with comma as the separator. I managed to do it with this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(U.name,', ') 
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NLSSORT(U.name,'NLS_SORT=polish'))
  FROM users U
  WHERE(U.birth_date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2);
```

The problem is that Polish characters like 'ą','ę' etc. are not displayed correctly in the result. How can I fix that?

Polish characters are not diplayed correctly in SQL Developer; for example I have users
'Grzegorz Brzęcki-Dębina' and 'Paweł Kukiz', and in the output I get 
'Grzegorz-Brz*cki-D*bina, Pawe* Kukiz'.

```
select name from users
```

Displays it correctly. 
Columns are NVARCHAR2.

Man u are a genius :) That link helped a lot. All i need was:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CAST(U.name AS VARCHAR2(10)),', ') 
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NLSSORT(U.name,'NLS_SORT=polish'))
  FROM users U
  WHERE(U.birth_date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2);
```

Thx :)

Comment: They are not displayed correctly where? With some dummy data this seems to work OK, in SQL Developer as a script or statement. Can you add some sample data and what you currently see and expect to see for that data? (Do you mean the characters aren't displayed, or that the order isn't what you expect?)

Comment: But `select name from users` displays them properly in SQL Developer? That seems odd. Which version are you using, and which encoding do you have set; and, I suppose, are the columns varchar2 or nvarchar2, and what are your database and national character sets?

Comment: Would this thread possibly help ? https://community.oracle.com/thread/2453760?start=0&tstart=0  seems they give a workaround ?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a variation [of this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28812445/266304). What is NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET? The cast might work, but you might need to use the convert option; depends whether the characters can be converted... (edit) the RAW approach in the thread Ditto linked to might work better though. I don't think I can easily replicate this in my environment, or test any of the workarounds.