# Getting NiFi to read properly formatted JSON from an Oracle view without transforming/reformatting it

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, apache-nifi

Brief high-level overview: trying to go Oracle --> NiFi --> Solr.

I have been trying to get data out of an Oracle view into NiFi as JSON for ultimate streaming into Solr. For ordinary columns (varchar2, integer, etc.) this is not a problem. A simple `select * from view` from an ExecuteSQLRecord processor works great; the data in Nifi is properly formed JSON and is streamed into Solr perfectly.

The problem is, I have some columns that represent 1:N data, i.e., arrays. I am replacing an outdated process, swapping NiFi for an obsolete ETL tool. The way this used to work for these 1:N columns was that the old ETL tool would create XML of this format:

```
<results>
    <row>
        <field name="town">sleepy town</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="town">boring town</field>
    </row>
</results>
```

Apparently, there was some magic in the built-in Solr component in this old ETL tool where this XML format was transformed so that it ends up looking like a JSON string array in Solr:

```
"array_column":
    ["sleepy town",
     "boring town"]
```

I was originally creating XML in the Oracle view to mimic the old ETL tool before I realized that this magical transformation was going away. Since all the other ordinary columns (varchar2, integer, etc.) were coming through NiFi and to Solr properly, I thought I would reformat these 1:N columns so that they looked like JSON arrays, which I did.

The problem is, no matter what I do in NiFi (or in the view in Oracle), NiFi will only treat the data coming in from Oracle as a monolithic string. In other words, what the view returns in Oracle is this:

```
select array_column from view

ARRAY_COLUMN
------------
["sleepy_town","boring town"]
```

But in NiFi, when looking at the data provenance for the ExecuteSQLRecord processor, this is what it shows:

```
[
  {
    "SOME_ORDINARY_COLUMNS":"Everything looks great!",
    "ARRAY_COLUMN": "[\"sleepy town\",\"boring town\"]",
    "MORE_ORDINARY_COLUMNS":"Everything looks great!",
  }
]
```

and when I get Avro involved, it looks like this:

```
{
  "SOME_ORDINARY_COLUMNS" : {
    "string" : "Everything looks great!"
  },
  "ARRAY_COLUMN" : {
    "string" :  "[\"sleepy town\",\"boring town\"]"
  },
  "MORE_ORDINARY_COLUMNS" : {
    "string" : "Everything looks great!"
  }
}
```

I have tried many things:

- Changed the Schema Write Strategy on the JsonRecordSetWriter to Set
  'avro.schema' Attribute so that I could look at the schema, then
  used "Use 'Schema Text' Property" to try to force the ARRAY_COLUMN to be an array of strings (many variations)
- Many variations of using an Avro writer and sending the output to a
  QueryRecord processor with either Avro or JSON readers, with both inferred and explicit schemas specified
- Setting the JSONPath in the JsonPathReader for the QueryRecord processor to $.ARRAY_COLUMN[*]
  and/or $.ARRAY_COLUMN.[*]
- Changing the query in ExecuteSQLRecord to `select JSON_OBJECT(...)`
  instead of `select *` (also tried dot notation with the JSON_OBJECT as a subquery)
- Investigated VARRAY and nested tables in Oracle, but that seemed like
  the wrong direction

All of these either resulted in a "can't convert string to array" error in NiFi, or the 1:N column remaining a monolithic string with double-quotes escaped.

I'm sure there are other variations I've tried between the lines related to these, but I've been fighting with this for a couple days, and it's becoming blurry. I know in Oracle, with JSON_OBJECT there's a "FORMAT JSON" option that tells Oracle, "Hey, this IS JSON, so don't reformat it!" I wish there was something like that in Nifi, some way to tell NiFi to look at what's coming in from Oracle as properly formatted JSON that doesn't need to be monkeyed with.

I haven't done anything with it, but I imagine I could get really fancy and write some groovy or something, but I am really trying to do this with just native NiFi processors without having to lean on custom scripting.

Comment: If you're using Oracle 21c then among your attempts, did you try `select cast(array_column as json) from ...`? That gets a different data type (JSON/119, rather than VARCHAR2/1 or CLOB/112). No idea if that would allow NiFi to interpret it differently - just a thought. And doesn't work in 19c or earlier. Otherwise supplying a collection rather than a string might be the way to go; or completely the other way and generate the full JSON doc from Oracle, if it would understand that and it's the mix that's confusing things. No idea about NiFi though! How was data supplied to the old ETL tool?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I had tangentially thought about that, but we're at (don't laugh) 12c. Sorry if it didn't come out in the list of what I've tried, but I did also try sending a full JSON doc to NiFi, which it promptly treated like a string and escaped all the double-quotes. I did start down the collection route, and I might start up that excursion again. Thanks.

Comment: Alex—so I had looked into VARRAY and nested tables early on, but it felt like overkill. At your suggestion to think about collections, I introduced a nested table to my view. My first experiments were with VARCHAR2, and it worked! But the actual data I'm using can often be over 4,000 characters, which means using CLOBs. When I switch everything over to CLOBs, the formatting in NiFi is still right, but the encoding comes out "\u0000&\u001,,H\u000", etc.. I may create a new post about that.

Comment: That sounds vaguely like a NCHAR issue; took me a while to find [this old issue with listagg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52080115/266304) which adds null characters, so slightly similar but probably not related. You don't seem to be using `NVARCHAR2` or `listagg()` (or `NCLOB`). Do you see the same issue running your query directly in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer?

Comment: Yeah, I actually switched it to NCLOB just to see what would happen. But, no, just straight CLOB. I was using listagg (actually xmlagg due to the length) when I was trying to send over a preformatted JSON array, but not now with nested tables. I had to attenuate the data so that I could actually take a look at it in SQL Developer (< 500 characters and < 5 rows in the nested table). Without that, SQL Developer would lock up. When I do that, the data looks fine in SQL Developer, i.e., plain ol' readable English, not the "\u" encoding. Still poking around. May post a new issue tomorrow.

Comment: FWIW, update here. First, I was wrong. I DID see the "\u" encoding on the Oracle side before it made it to NiFi. Then, not sure if this is what fixed it (I may still test it out), but I was using REPLACE in the view to escape embedded CR/LF and double-quotes, and that may have triggered something. When I went to just straight ```NVL(column1, '') || NVL(column2, '') || etc.``` the strange encoding went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I had considered using a collection, Alex Poole's first comment pushed me back in that direction, and that was what got it done. I switched around my view to use nested tables:

`create or replace type my_schema.clob_nested_table as table of clob`

Then in the view:

```
with main_query as
(
    select case_id, other_fields, more_fields, transformation1, transformation2
      from parent_table
      join lookup_table
      join another_lookup_table_etc
),
child_a as
(
    select a.case_id
           cast(multiset(select to_clob(nvl(b.column1, '') || nvl(b.column2, '') || nvl(b.etc, ''))
                           from child_table_a b
                          where a.case_id = b.case_id) as my_schema.clob_nested_table) as child_a_data
      from main_query a
)
select a.case_id, a.other_fields, a.more_fields, a.transformation1, a.transformation2,
       b.child_a_data
  from main_query a
  left outer join child_a b on a.case_id = b.case_id
```

Of course, that's pseudo-code, and not 100% syntactically correct, but it shows the magic. There are 54 of these "child" tables, so it's a rather lengthy view, and there's a lot of transformation going on.

The solution was to use nested tables, and the data shows up in NiFi looking like a properly formatted JSON array, and then gets sent off to Solr, where it looks exactly as it should. Thanks, Alex!

**UPDATE:**

A colleague ran up against a similar problem, and he ended up solving it with a Jolt transformation. So I tried that out for my flow, and it worked like magic. I had looked at Jolt transformations, but I will admit, I had never touched Jolt, and the learning curve looked steeper than I wanted to commit.

But basically, once you have your one-to-many data comma-separated in a single column (via `listagg` or `xmlagg`), pass it through a `JoltTransformJSON` processor with the following specification:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": { "*": ""}
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": { "*": { "MyFirstCSVColumn": "=split(',',@(1,&))" } }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": { "*": { "MyNextCSVColumn": "=split(',',@(1,&))" } }
  }
]
```

That first `shift` operation catches all the "normal" columns in your table. Also, because some of my data had embedded commas, I ended up using the backwards single-quote (`) as my delimiter, starting with the `listagg`/`xmlagg`and also in the Jolt specification.